# How to update excel file back end using jsp/ html front end client side itself

Tags: javascript, html, oracle10g, database-connection, excel-2007

I am a student trying to do this please guide me how to do.

I have **excel file 2007**(.xlsx) with two column numbers A and B.

```
Sno     A       B          C
1     10.6729   59.9258    ?
2     10.4005   59.827     ?
3     10.6794   59.9254
4     10.3589   59.959
5     10.5006   59.9459
6     10.4924   59.9004
7     10.5006   59.9459
8     10.4517   59.7901
```

I need these to numbers A and B in my html text boxes when I ask for S.NO.
So that I can do some operation, run **Java script** and return back to excel file in C column with result in corresponding S.No.

Please guide me which server and what I need to do here to reach my goal.
Thanks in advance.

I saved excel file as xml. file while saving. so I have xml file here like

```js
            <script>
            function loadXMLDoc() {
              var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                  myFunction(xmlhttp);
                }
              };
              xmlhttp.open("GET", "Xmlexcelfile.xml", true);
              xmlhttp.send();
            }
            function myFunction(xml) {
              var i;
              var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
              var table="<tr><th>BookingID</th><th>FromLon</th></tr>";
              var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Row");
              for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
                table += "<tr><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("A")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("B")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td></tr>";
              }
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
            }
            </script>
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <style>
        table,th,td {
          border : 1px solid black;
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th,td {
          padding: 5px;
        }
        </style>
        <body>

        <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get my details</button>
        <br><br>
        <table id="demo"></table>

        script code here


        </body>
        </html>
```

now this is also not working I mean I think I need to put some server here.
Actually I need to know the details of how to get/put data from xlsn sheet through jsp pages/html pages as told above.

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: just give me outline what database to use and how can I get the data. any links will be helpful. will the data be saved in database be automatically done after doing this. without a click of a button